# How cannot localization of any integral domain respect to maximal ideal not be integrally closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, localization

Suppose that there is integral domain $I$. Now we take localization $I_m$ of $I$ respect to its maximal ideal $m$. $I_m$'s elements will consist of $a/b$ where $a \in I$ and $b \in m$.

But integral closedness is defined respect to field of fractions of $I_m$ and the field of fractions of $I_m$ is a subset of the field of fractions of $I$. Suppose that there exists elements not in $I_m$ but in field of fractions of $I$. Let those elements be $e=c/d$ where $c \in I$, $d \not \in m$. Then we can always multiply $e$ by $f/f$ where $f\in m$, which is same $e$, and $df \in m$. So it seems that it is impossible to find any element in the field of fraction of $I$ that is not in $I_m$. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: You get a denominator in $m$, but in the localization, you have precisely denominators not in $m$ (so the problem is that you wrote up the description of the localization incorrectly).

Comment: $f \in \mathcal m. f$ is not a unit in $I_{\mathcal m}.$ So the element $f/f \notin I_{\mathcal m}.$ Also field of fraction of $I_{\mathcal m}$ is equal to the field of fractions of $I.$

Comment: Then Wikipedia is wrong.. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring

Comment: No, you just read it incorrectly. When we localize "at a prime ideal" we are localizing the complement of that prime ideal, rather than the ideal itself (the latter would yield the zero ring).

Comment: So if we localize ring of rational integers with reference to prime ideal generated by 2, then 1/3 no longer equal to 2/6?

Comment: $2/6$ is not an element of the ring.